# Can I add child DOM html element after creating component dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I create instance of the `MyCcomponentContainer`:

```
 var factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponentContainer);
```

The template of MyComponentContainer:

```
<div #container class="myclass"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
```

Can I now change/edit/add something to this template after creating the component dynamically? For example I would like to add html that will replace the `<ng-content>`.

I'm looking for a way to replace ng-content with some HTML.

Comment: If you are creating a component inside the container, doesn't the html content become the injected components template?

Comment: You can pass `projectableNodes` to [createComponent](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#createComponent-anchor), this will be transcluded to `<ng-content>`.

Comment: projectableNodes can work with html templae file for example? It is only for creating the nodes by code? What I'm asking is can html-file.html template be transclude by code somehow?